# Is it possible to assign a class inside of a stylesheet

Tags: css, sass

I'm wanting to do something like:

```
.devise_links a {
  assign-class: 'btn'
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need to use Javascript to do that.

But I don't understand the point. Why do you want something like this?

Another thing you can do with SASS is to [extend](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend) another class though.

Comment: Hey I'm giving you the tick because I think you understood what I meant.. and I really like the @extend feature. Unfortunately this looks to only work on the same stylesheet, which is ashame because I want to pull in the classes from twitter bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks. Then there is 2 options. Using javascript, or download only the "button" CSS from the [Bootstrap customizer](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html), and add the `.devise_links a`

Comment: I don't know LESS (I'm using SASS), but since Bootstrap is written on LESS, maybe you can simply extend the `.btn` class

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can achieve that goal using javascript.

But, and I think this may solve your dilemma, why not just create two classes?

For example, in case you didn't know, you can write css like the following:

```
.devise_links a {
/* your code for all links with the ".devise_links" class  */    
}

.devise_links .device_links_btn a {
/* your code for all links with both the ".devise_links" class and the ".device_links_btn" class */
}
```

Hope this helps!